# Java Selenium printing table rows repeatedly for first page only

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here is my code:

```
public class Test 
{        
    private static String table         = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]";
    private static String tr            = table+ "/tbody/tr";
    private final static String next    = table+"/preceding::a[text()='Next'][last()]";
    private final static String yesGotIt = "//body/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-banner \")]/div/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-button-wrapper \")]/button";

    private static void scrape() throws Exception 
    {
        int count = 1;
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(yesGotIt)).click();
        
        while (count <= 3) {
            //Declare rows here - previous page's data will not repeatedly print
            String rows = "";
            System.out.println(count);

            // Declare WebElement, List here
            WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table));
            List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element.findElements(By.xpath(tr));

            for (WebElement trElement : tr_collection) 
            {
                List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
                for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) 
                {
                    rows += tdElement.getText() + "\t";
                }
                rows = rows + "\n";
            }

            System.out.println(rows);
            
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(next)));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(next)).click();
            count += driver.findElements(By.xpath(next)).size();            

            //refresh page to ignore StaleElementReferenceException
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(next)));
        }
    }

}
```

There are two tables of same class in one page. The aforementioned code works fine when I test first table by using xpath as `"(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[0]"` but when I try to test second table by changing its xpath as `"(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]";` then its scraping first page data repeatedly for `Next` pages despite displaying other pages data

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As visibility is focused on first table, last table's page change is not observable. To focus on actual table's next button JavascriptExecutor is used and updated the whole code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Test 
{
    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        openBrowser();
        //System.out.println(scrape());
        scrape();
        //closeBrowser();
    }

    //private static String table = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[1]";
    private static String table = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]";
    private static String tr = table + "/tbody/tr";
    private final static String next = table + "/preceding::a[text()='Next'][1]";
    private final static String yesGotIt = "//body/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-banner \")]/div/div[contains(concat(\" \",normalize-space(@class),\" \"),\" gdpr-button-wrapper \")]/button";

    private static void scrape() throws Exception 
    {
        // WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table));
        // List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element.findElements(By.xpath(tr));

        int count = 1;
        // String rows = "";
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(yesGotIt)).click();
        while (count <= 3) {
            //Declare rows here - previous page's data will not repeatedly print
            String rows = "";

            System.out.println(count);

            // Declare WebElement, List here
            WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(table));
            List<WebElement> tr_collection = table_element.findElements(By.xpath(tr));

            for (WebElement trElement : tr_collection) 
            {
                List<WebElement> td_collection = trElement.findElements(By.xpath("td"));
                for (WebElement tdElement : td_collection) 
                {
                    rows += tdElement.getText() + "\t";
                }
                rows = rows + "\n";
            }

            System.out.println(rows);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(next)));
            
            //scroll to next button
            JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(next));
            je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", we);
            we.click();
            
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(next)).click();
            count += driver.findElements(By.xpath(next)).size();
            //System.out.println(count);

            //refresh page to ignore StaleElementReferenceException
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(next)));
        }
    }

    private static void openBrowser() 
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "E:\\eclipse-workspace\\src\\working\\selenium\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.iata.org/en/publications/directories/code-search/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private static void closeBrowser() 
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```